# Как вывести под-категории только одной конкретной категории в Magento?

Tags: php, magento

Я использую файл left.phtml для образца и не знаю как правильно записи, чтобы выводились под-категории от одной главной.
Пример кода:

```
<?php if (!Mage::registry('current_category')) return ?>    
<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>    
<?php $_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count(); ?>    
<?php if($_count): ?>    
<div class="block block-layered-nav block-layered-nav--no-filters">    
    <div class="block-content toggle-content open">    
        <dl id="narrow-by-list2">    
            <dt><?php echo $this->__('Меню') ?></dt>    
            <dd>    
                <ol>    
                <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>    
                    <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>    
                    <li>    
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>>    
                            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?>    
                            <span class="count">(<?php echo $_category->getProductCount() ?>)</span>    
                        </a>    
                    </li>    
                    <?php endif; ?>    
                <?php endforeach ?>    
                </ol>    
            </dd>    
        </dl>    
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script>    
    </div>    
</div>    
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Список дочерних категорий для конкретной категории, зная её id, можно получить так:

```
$categoryId = 3;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$childrenCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
```

Comment: У меня нет возможности писать комментарии к чужим ответам, поэтому пишу здесь. 

Уточните вопрос, вы хотите сделать вывод категорий в шаблоне, указанном в первом вопросе (left.phtml)?